# How to wake up the Camera in Android?

Tags: android, camera

I would need to wake up my camera when i click a button on my App. After that it takes a picture and save it to the sdcard and display the path of that image as Toast? How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many samples out there on the web, i.e.

http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/

especially look at:

http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Picture/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PictureDemo.java